# Java: How to create a method from a user input

Tags: java, input, methods

I am new to Java and I am trying to figure out how I can use methods from a value that a user has entered. I have used the Java scanner and understand how this works but I haven't been able to work out how I can create a method that uses this value that a user has entered.

I am wanting to create something really simple so I can understand such as user enters a number, and then a method that does this number multiplied by 10. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious but Iv'e been trying for hours and I cant work it out.

This is what I have below, but when I try to add a method underneath I get different types of errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        String num = number.nextLine();
```

Comment: Are you converting/parsing that string to a number before trying to multiply it?

Comment: Sorry I read this wrong first time, yes I think so, it would have to be converted from string to a number to do calculations on it? is that correct

Comment: Yes, if you read the data as string it must be converted at some point. But don't worry too much about it, I was just trying to help on what could be the cause of the problems you had so you can check this next time

Answer (score 1):

Once you've assigned the user input to a variable you can use it like any other variable and pass it into a method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // read user input and assign to the 'num' variable
    int num = in.nextInt();
    // call the method we made and pass the num into it
    myMethod(num);
  }
  // here we define our method and give it one parameter, num
  public static void myMethod(int num) {
    // multiply num variable by 10 and print it
    System.out.println(num*10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, it looks so easy now when you say it like that haha, should've thought of this. Thank you for the help

Comment: @BarCode no problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to do the next

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        int num = number.nextInt()*10;
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question, you don't actually use another method anywhere besides the `main`.

Comment: because it is not necessary, if you can use or reduce the code, it is much better

Comment: But the point of the question is to learn how to use methods, not to actually use the code (which you did not help with at all).  Also it is not true reducing code is always better, there are definitely times where abstracting logic could increase code but it is better practice.  For example, do you never use getters and setters and only ever use public class fields?  A private class variable is longer code, but better practice.